# Reasons why $_POST would not echo html?

Tags: php, html, post, echo

I'm new to PHP and trying to figure this out. I've been endlessly searching the internet for an answer to this, but nothing I've found, even on this site, has helped. There are a ton of similar questions posted, but none I've seen have answers that have solved my problem. The general issue is that my php file will not echo my html code.

I took this code straight from an online tutorial (it worked on that website) but when I try to run it from my computer, it doesn't work. The php code is called but the echo part is blank. I am running this from my AppServ www directory (Windows, if that makes any difference).

HTML file "Testing.html":

```
<html> 
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP file "welcome.php":

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Things I've tried:

1. Saving both as .php files
2. Using $_REQUEST instead of $_POST
3. Adding ids as well as names to the input items in the html file
4. Running from other directories

I'm out of ideas! Any suggestions?

Comment: your code is working.check your URL once.`localhost/direcotoryname/testing.html`.

Comment: Guessing you opened it from `file://`, rather than `http://`

Comment: BTW, what website did you get this awful code from?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to run it by simply opening the file in my browser instead of using the localhost url. I've tried this way now but I'm getting an error message that "localhost is not available right now." Any ideas on where I should proceed from here?

Comment: And to answer Alexander, the website was http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: @user5588198 so that the source of that terrible code, i would really suggest you to not use w3schools for learning, try http://www.phptherightway.com/ instead

Comment: Such code are for demonstration and learning purposes only, you should not use it for production

Comment: @user5588198: Seems you don't have a local sever installed either. Setup a local server before trying this code. Accessing the file directly with a browser isn't going to process PHP code. You need a server with PHP installed. Consider WAMP if you are on Windows.

Comment: @rehmat I have AppServ installed, and mySQL is able to connect to localhost (and just yesterday I was able to run some html/php code through localhost). I don't think anything has changed. (I currently have mySQL connected to localhost, but I tried disconnecting it and running the code again in case for some reason that was blocking it, but it didn't help).

Comment: Note: I've tried various browsers as well, but with the same result :/

Comment: Ahh, solved it. I put the port number into the url and all is well now. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You need to first check weather `$_POST` is set or not before printing out on page

you can do this by using `isset()` function like below

```
isset($_POST["name"])
```

your code is vulnerable to **XSS**

> You must sanitize any user input before  it rendered back to the browser

just use `htmlspecialchars();` for that

```
 htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Good Read :

1. [**XSS cheat sheet**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Cheat_Sheet)
2. [**PHP the right way**](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, solved it. I put the port number into the url (eg localhost:8080) and all is well now. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: also dont use wamp or xamp use virtual machine with linux for server